# Unable to post data to ASP.Net Web API Controller using ExtJS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, extjs4, asp.net-web-api

I am using ASP.Net MVC Web API for the first time. I have two functions written in my controller. First one gets the list of records and the second one is used to post data. My function to get the list of records work fine whereas the function to post data always fails. Here is the controller code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using MyApp.Entity.Models;
using DHT.Library;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Collections;

namespace MyApp.Server.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/myspace")]
    public class MySpaceController : BaseAppController
    {
        public MySpaceController()
        {
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [Route("")]
        public List<MyApp.Entity.Models.myspace> Get()
        {
            //logic to return records. Works fine.
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        public object Post(JObject data)
        {
            string result = "";

            string name;
            JToken nameToken;
            data.TryGetValue("name", out nameToken);
            name = (string)nameToken;

            string address;
            JToken addressToken;
            data.TryGetValue("address", out addressToken );
            address = (string)addressToken;

            //Logic to write data to database. Doesn't work.
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I am trying to post data to the controller using ExtJS:

```
AddNewTab: function (button) {
        var me = this,
            tabs = me.getAppMain().down('userpanel'),
            win = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
                title: 'Add User',
                modal: true,
                height: '20%',
                width: '25%',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'form',
                    layout: 'form',
                    bodyPadding: '5 5 0',
                    id: 'addUserForm',
                    frame: false,
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        fieldLabel: 'User Name',
                        maxLength: 25,
                        enforceMaxLength: true,
                        allowBlank: false,
                        id: 'TextUserName'
                    }],
                    buttons: [{
                        text: 'Add',
                        handler: function () {
                            if (this.up('form').getForm().isValid()) {
                                var _Name = this.up('form').getForm().findField('TextUserName').getValue();

                                Ext.Ajax.request({
                                    url: apiUrl + 'myspace',//The URL of controller
                                    mode: 'POST',
                                    params: {
                                        'name': _Name,
                                        'address': 'Dummy Address'
                                    },
                                    success: function (resp) {
                                        var respObj = Ext.decode(resp.responseText);
                                        if (respObj == 'added') {
                                            Ext.Msg.alert('Success', 'User added.');
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            Ext.Msg.alert('Error', respObj);
                                        }
                                    },
                                    failure: function (resp) {
                                        Ext.Msg.alert('Error', 'There was an error.');
                                    }
                                });
                                this.up('form').up('window').close();
                            }
                            else {
                                Ext.Msg.alert('Error', 'Please enter User Name.');
                            }
                        }
                    }, {
                        text: 'Cancel',
                        handler: function () {
                            this.up('form').up('window').close();
                        }
                    }]
                }]
            });
        win.show();
    }
```

Whenever I try to add a user, I get 'There was an error' message. What step am I missing?

Comment: Hi did you find the error? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public object Post(string name, string address)
{
    // your logic
}
```

and set a breakpoint at open curly brace check to see if the value of name and address get passed.